# How to allow strings in a float input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

So I'm asking my user to input a number(float)
`num=float(input("Please enter a number"))`
but I'm also asking the user to enter the value "q" to quit
and since this variable can only take in floats, the program is not letting the user enter the string ("q"), is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Expect a string and parse it has as a float only if it is not equal to `q`.

```
temp = input("Please enter a number")
if not temp == "q":
   num = float(temp)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to automatically cast your input to a float. If you don't want to do this in all cases you should add some `if/else` logic in here:

```
input_string = input("Please enter a number")
if not input_string == 'q':
    num = float(intput_string)
```

Or, to be a bit more pythonic you should do a try/except strategy:

```
input_string = input("Please enter a number")
try:
    num = float(input_string)
except ValueError:
    if input_string == 'q':
        # However you exit
```

The second is technically more pythonic according to the `EAFP` principle (https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html)